# List all the functions inside angularjs controller

Tags: angularjs, list, methods, angular-controller

I have an angularjs controller, inside that I have method1 and method2 defined.
Now I need a way to fetch information of the defined method inside the angular controller.
I tried with the $scope variable It gives me access to the functions but what I would need here is to get all the methods defined as list(or something similar).
when I say `$scope.getAllMethods` it should give me information of `method1` and `method2` which is defined inside the controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How is [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/WVkWHIsUySm0PPusPDsh?p=preview)?

1. Get all properties of $scope.
2. Test if they are of function type.
3. If they are, push to an array and stringify them.

   ```
   $scope.methods = [];
   $scope.getAllMethods = function() {

   console.log($scope);

   var props = Object.getOwnPropertyNames($scope);

   for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) {
     if (typeof($scope[props[i]]) === 'function') {
       $scope.methods.push({
         'name': props[i],
         'function': $scope[props[i]].toString()
       })
     }
   }
   ```

   }

Comment: Thanks Brian Its working. in my case i dont need the `'function': $scope[props[i]].toString()` I only need the name. anyways its working

Comment: `angular.forEach($scope, function (value, key) {
            if (typeof (value) == 'function')
                $scope.operations.push(key);
        });`